# How to add draggable-handle for configure product variants in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.3, uicomponent, forms

How to add `draggable-handle` for **configure product's variants** in Magento 2 ?

**I can see there is a similar behavior in the `related products` when editing a product.**

[image]

> Like related products

- Row drag and drop option `draggable-handle`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add sort order column by overriding below listed files:

1. Override vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/ConfigurablePanel.php into your custom module and Add column name in getRows() function.
2. Override vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Data/AssociatedProducts.php and Add column name in prepareVariations() function.
3. Override vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Variations/Config/Matrix.php and Add column name in prepareMatrix[].
4. Override /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/super/matrix.phtml and Add your custom in  for the column name and add code to retrieve data in .

Please do have a look at solution.